# How to include double quote(") in regular expression

Tags: regex, xml, validation

Does any one know how to include double quote in regular expression.I wrote this regex but unable to include the double quote

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="KeywordsRegex" runat="server" 
 ValidationExpression="^[+\-\!\(\)\:\^\[\]\{\}\~\*\?\&&\||].*$" 
 ControlToValidate="Keywords" ErrorMessage="Search keyword is not valid." 
 Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: this solve it definitelly \22\42.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616190/quotes-inside-validationexpression-for-regularexpressionvalidator

Answer (score 13):

Try putting a backslash (`\`) followed by `&quot;`. That would be proper XML.

Comment: thanks Oscar broman your trick is working now it look like this    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="KeywordsRegex" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[^\&quot;\'\+\-\!\(\)\:\^\[\]\{\}\~\*\?\&&\||].*$" ControlToValidate="Keywords" ErrorMessage="Search keyword is not valid." Text="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

Answer (score 1):

have you tried escaping the double quote with a backslash?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to double escape, eg `\\\"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape it : 
Replace each " by \"