# allow parentheses and other symbols in regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've made this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$
```

Supports:

```
letters [uppercase and lowercase]
numbers [from 0 to 9]
underscores [_]
dots [.]
hyphens [-]
```

Now, I want to add these:

```
spaces [ ]
comma [,]
exclamation mark  [!]
parenthesis [()]
plus [+]
equal [=]
apostrophe [']
double quotation mark ["]
at [@]
dollar [$]
percent [%]
asterisk [*]
```

For example, this code accept only some of the symbols above:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,-!()+=“”„@"$#%*]*$
```

Returns:

> Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 16

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Make sure to put hyphen `-` either at start or at end in character class otherwise it needs to be escaped. Try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,!()+=`,"@$#%*-]*$
```

Also note that because `*` it will even match an empty string. If you don't want to match empty strings then use `+`:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,!()+=`,"@$#%*-]+$
```

Or better:

```
^[\w .,!()+=`,"@$#%*-]+$
```

**TEST:**

```
$text = "_.,!()+=,@$#%*-";
if(!preg_match('/\A[\w .,!()+=`,"@$#%*-]+\z/', $text)) {
   echo "error.";
}
else {
   echo "OK.";
}
```

**Prints:**

```
OK.
```

Answer (score 4):

The hyphen is being treated as a range marker -- when it sees `,-!` it thinks you're asking for a range  all characters in the charset that fall between `,` and `!` (ie the same way that `A-Z` works. This isn't what you want.

Either make sure the hyphen is the last character in the character class, as it was before, or escape it with a backslash.

I would also point out that the quote characters you're using `“”„` are part of an extended charset, and are not the same as the basic ASCII quotes `"'`. You may want to include both sets in your pattern. If you do need to include the non-ASCII characters in the pattern, you should also add the `u` modifier after the end of your pattern so it correctly picks up unicode characters.

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping your regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\(\)\*]`

Check if this help you: [How to escape regular expression special characters using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115150/how-to-escape-regular-expression-special-characters-using-javascript)

Comment: None of the newly-added characters need to be escaped when they appear inside a character class (which they do).  The only problematic character is the hyphen, and the other responders have explained how to deal with that.

Comment: Oh, and possibly the fancy quotes (`“”„`). But [Spudley's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660140/20938) deals with those.

Answer (score 2):

Inside of a character class `[...]` the hyphen `-` has a special meaning unless it is the first or last character, so you need to escape it:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _.,\-!()+=“”„@"$#%*]*$
```

None of the other characters need to be escaped in the character class (except `]`).  You will also need to escape the quote indicating the string.  e.g.

```
'/[\']/'
"/[\"]/"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9*&!_^%$#!~@,=+,./\|}{)(~`?][;:\'""-]{0,8}$

use this [link to test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809049/how-to-include-double-quote-in-regular-expression)

trick is i reverse ordered the parenthesis and other braces that took care of some problems. And for square braces you must escape them